# C Program - Properly initialize and print char array with or without pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to print out the array row_col but am misplacing my pointer and or just declaring my array improperly. I have tried various methods to get it to print out correctly, but at this point, I believe I am only getting memory addresses rather than the actual information that is stored at the given array position. Any help in finding my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "find_word.h"
#include <string.h>

void word_find(char stringof_3 [3][3], char the_word[3]){

    char *row_col;
    int print_letter = 0;
    int word_count = 0;

    if(stringof_3[0][0] == the_word[0] && stringof_3[0][1] == the_word[1] && stringof_3[0][2] == the_word[2])
            row_col = "0,0  ";
    else if(stringof_3[0][0] == the_word[0] && stringof_3[1][0] == the_word[1] && stringof_3[2][0] == the_word[2])
            row_col = "0,0  ";
    else if(stringof_3[1][0] == the_word[0] && stringof_3[1][1] == the_word[1] && stringof_3[1][2] == the_word[2])
            row_col = "1,0  ";
    else if(stringof_3[2][0] == the_word[0] && stringof_3[2][1] == the_word[1] && stringof_3[2][2] == the_word[2])
            row_col = "2,0  ";
    else if(stringof_3[0][1] == the_word[0] && stringof_3[1][1] == the_word[1] && stringof_3[2][1] == the_word[2])
            row_col = "0,1  ";
    else if(stringof_3[0][2] == the_word[0] && stringof_3[1][2] == the_word[1] && stringof_3[2][2] == the_word[2])
            row_col = "0,2 ";
    else
            row_col = "-1,-1";
    for(print_letter = 0; print_letter < 3; print_letter++){
            printf("%c", the_word[print_letter]);
    }
    printf(" found at: ");
    for(word_count = 0; word_count < 6; word_count++){
            printf("%d", row_col[word_count]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It looks like the text got cut off because of a column restriction (the $ at the end).  Could you repost the entire code?

Comment: Sorry, I just posted the corrected code. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply assign a constant string to a char * in that way.
Use `strcpy()` (found in string.h) to copy a string into it.

```
strcpy(row_col, "0,0   ");
```

That said, your way of doing things is altogether strange. For example, you print row_col one character at a time using a for loop, when you don't even need a loop. You can just do

```
printf("%s", row_col);
```

Also to compare each row in stringof_3 with the_word, you needn't compare each character individually. Just do

```
strcmp(stringof_3[i], the_word);
```

where i is iterated from 0 to 2. strcmp() returns 0 if both strings are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is no need to manually iterate all of the characters in `row_col`.  It is a `char*` value that is always null terminated (it is only initialized with string literals).  Hence it can be printed by using the `%s` format specifier.

```
printf("%s", row_col);
```

Considering that you only assign string literals to `row_col` it would be better to declare it as the following to indicate it's non-changing behavior

```
const char* row_col;
```